# `Simple_form` + nested model + CanCan: creating new child updates parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, cancan, simple-form

Environment: Rails 3.2.13 + `simple_form` 2.1.0 + CanCan 1.6.10 + etc.

Model thumbnail: `Article`s have authors (`User`s) and `Comment`s. `Comment`s are a nested resource within `Article`s. The `Comment` model includes content, the commenter (currently logged-in user ID) and article ID.

Issue: Creating a new `Comment` on an `Article` causes the `Article` to be updated, understandably. At present, CanCan's `Ability` class is hardwired to allow that `Article` to be updated by that user. I want to limit that to allowing the update if the `Article`'s `Comment`s — and *only* that field — are updated. I've been poking around in `pry` for a couple of hours trying to figure out how to tell what's being updated, and am drawing a blank so far.

Models are posted in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jdickey/5784340) in response to Michael Szyndel's question.

Help?

Comment: Article being updated on Comment creation is not understandable unless you have counter cache. Could you include your model associations?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you having trouble controlling your association's autosave callbacks AND having trouble detecting non-persisted modifications?

Comment: @crftr, I'm having (at least) two intertwined problems:


1. I want to use CanCan's Ability class to limit updates to Article content to the Article's author only, while permitting any logged-in user to create comments on that article


2. I want to understand if achieving that effect is most practical in CanCan, or if I should be doing something differently in my `InheritedResources::Base`-derived controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-lieu of identifying the culprit, *which I would guess is related to the reliance on* `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, I would rather offer a solution-- implement a `before_update` callback on the `Article` model.

```
before_update :verify_update_authorization

# virtual attribute to supply CanCan a user candidate
def initiator
  @initiating_user if @initiating_user
end

def initiator=(user)
  @initiating_user = user
end

private

  def verify_update_authorization
    return false if Ability.new(initiator).cannot?(:update, self)
  end
```

The controllers would then need to set the Article's virtual attribute when an update is desired.  *In this particular case, it would be proper to override the InheretedResources update action*.

Comment: That was one of the 3 things that needed doing to make the whole thing work, and I was unlikely to have figured it out on my own in a survivable timeframe given the track I'd been on. 

The other things were remembering to call `article.comments.build` whenever I created a new Article object, and the egregiously funky gyrations a create- or edit-comment view needed to go through. This last, judging by StackOverflow traffic, is obviously equally obscure to many others, and motivates me to look at ActionView template replacements such as [Erector](https://github.com/erector/erector).

Comment: If I could offer you an unsolicited opinion,

Comment: It appears that persistence and user interaction concerns are becoming tightly coupled.  I would argue that this is a code smell.  My suggestion would be to offload the user interaction actions to a completely different controller, non-ActiveRecord model, and view. http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/, specifically the form object pattern.  It's more work to implement but the isolation is refreshing.

Comment: Fervently agree that the current architecture needs surgical application of several chainsaws, particularly decoupling of persistence and domain logic. Given that a medium-term future deliverable of our main project is a full-featured REST/JSON API, and especially given that we hope to get scalability nailed before it becomes a fail-whale-class issue, there's a lot to mull over here. Having a quarter of the dev team that our business plan called for just makes things more "interesting".

Thanks again!